# Php CPU cycle benchmarking

Tags: php, memory, benchmarking, cpu

We have ported an important module of a website to Symfony from plain PHP.

This module has a lot of page hits, and we need to judge additional hardware requirements (if any) because of this.  We want to benchmark the extra memory and CPU cycles web pages take after porting.

Is there any existing tool or a function in PHP to get these statistics?  I have come across the `getrusage` function in php, but it does not seem to be reliable.

Comment: Don't mean to be pedantic, but it's spelled "Symfony".

Answer (score 3):

[XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) can be used to create callgrind files and function traces.

Former explains where in a request time has been spent at, counts of function calls and such. [KCacheGrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) can be used to inspect that data, for example.

Latter can be used to see how certain function paths in reality works, inspect memory usages of functions and such in per-function basis.

Comment: :- Xdebug and KcacheGrind type of tool will also take the cpu and memory resources and will work on one request at a time, we want to do bench-marking using tools like apache benchmark etc and then use the cpu time and memory logs by the tools to see what is the pattern on high load.

Comment: Those cachegrind files can be appended instead of overwriting for each request. Though it adds quite a bit of extra load to actions, relative usage is most of time correct.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony and most other frameworks ive seen offers an inbuilt benchmarking system which ive found quiet useful.

Also see if you find this useful.
http://www.markround.com/archives/30-LigHTTPd-and-Apache-Symfony-benchmarks.html

Comment: please refer me to inbuilt benchmarking system of symphony. On apache benchmarking, I am going to do that too. I will probably use jmeter or siege to hit different pages on website. ab supports only one

Answer (score 0):

Instead of benchmarking this way, you could maybe make a stress test on a development server that is equivalent to the production one, with equivalent requests per second, for example [Apache Benchmarking Tool](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html). (And don't forget to install an op-code cache).

Comment: Yes we would do that, but if we get cpu time and memory pattern with this then we can plan better, as there are many other modules on web site and simulating web site traffic would simulate them as well. We want to have load consumed per module type of stats, to do capacity planning.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Symfony** is one of the best frameworks for profiling PHP projects. It has some great tools built in.

There was a great talk about your options at Symfony Conf 2010.

The slide show is here http://www.slideshare.net/old_sound/debugging-and-profiling-symfony-apps

Comment: Jon that is a fair lot. Need to go through them. Would you like to recommend one on the basis of my need. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

See our [PHP Profiling Tools](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Profilers/PHPProfiler.html).  You can get relative counts with minimal overhead, or you can get timing on methods and call trees.